# Sqrt(n) time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am new to time complexities and asymptotic notation. I was looking at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9TlHvipP5yA to figure out the time complexity of a piece of code shown below

The code concludes that the time complexity for the code below is O(Sqrt(n));

When I supply different n values, I am expecting Sqrt(n) # of outputs but this doesn't verify the O(Sqrt(n)) analysis. Can someone please explain why it is so?

For example if I have n = 10, I am expecting Sqrt(10) outputs which is ~ 3 outputs or 4 if you round up I guess. IS this illogical?

Thanks in advance.

```
p = 0;
for( int i = 0; p <= n; i++){
  p = p + i;
  System.out.println(p);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I have fixed the code.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Big O describes the asymptotic behavior (up to multiplication by a constant) for large values of n. You can't deduce what the time for n=10 will be from it.

Comment: OK so it is wrong to assume that if I have n = 100, I will have root(100) System.out.print statements?

Comment: No. If 100 is large enough to exhibit the asymptotic behavior then you'll get up to c*sqrt(100) prints for some constant c.

Comment: Cann you explain what you meant by this - Big O describes the asymptotic behavior (up to multiplication by a constant) for large values of n.????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Big O is not used to compute the number of instructions you are expected to execute. For a given n, calculating the square root of n will not give you the exact number of times the instruction executes. Big O describes what happens with your function **as input size gets very large**. Analysis of your function when n is 10 or even 100 does not apply to Big O.

When we say a function's time complexity is O(sqrt(n)), we mean that the function belongs in a class of functions where the time required is proportional to the square root of the value of n, **but only for very large values of n**.

If you watch the video, the instructor simplifies the k(k+1) / 2 term to k^2 by taking the leading term, because the k term becomes insignificant compared to the k^2 term, **when k is very large**.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation